# Avoiding System Ringtones in android using Ringtone Manager

Tags: android

I am using `RingtoneManager` to fetch ringtones and it returns all the ringtones including the system ones. How can I only fetch ringtones that are stored on the sd card and are not the system default ones?

Here is the code for my ringtone fetcher class

```
public class RingtoneHelper {

    public static List<Ringtone> fetchAvailableRingtones(Context context){

        List<Ringtone> ringtones = new ArrayList<>();
        RingtoneManager mgr = new RingtoneManager(context);
        mgr.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        int n = mgr.getCursor().getCount();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            ringtones.add(mgr.getRingtone(i));
        }

        return  ringtones;
    }

    public static void changeRingtone(Context context){

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("randomizer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!preferences.getBoolean("active", false))
            return;

        RingtoneManager mgr = new RingtoneManager(context);
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        int n = random.nextInt(mgr.getCursor().getCount());

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, mgr.getRingtoneUri(n));
    }
}
```